# Receiver location calculation based on Rinex navigation and observation files

Tags: gps, gnss

I am trying to calculate the location of the GNSS receiver using the data available in the Rinex navigation and observation files. As a first step I am trying to calculate the pseudo range using the tr and tsv. The problem is I could not locate the information of tr and tsv in the Rinex file.

Moreover, i can calculate the GPS system time using the GPS reference time and the offset. I can log GPS reference time and offset from my GPS receiver.

Is t and tsv are known variables in the following equations? af0,af1 and af2 are known and still trying to figure out toc.
Is toc the epoch time provided in terms of year/month/day/hour/min/sec?

The user shall correct the time received from the SV with the equation (in seconds)
t = tsv - tsv (1)
where
t = GPS system time (seconds),
tsv = effective SV PRN code phase time at message transmission time (seconds),
tsv = SV PRN code phase time offset (seconds).
The SV PRN code phase offset is given by
tsv = af0 + af1(t - toc) + af2(t - toc)
2 + tr (2